# how to get firebase oobcode in REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-authentication

i ma trying to make authentication system for my game i am stuck on the oobcode which is generated when the verify email is sent to email but to confirm this mail a oobCode is send by Firebase i want to know how to get Firebase rest API OOBCODE. i don't want to create a self server to dynamically handle i want to use Firebase option.
with REST API.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you exactly want to achieve. Do you ask how to get the oobCode? Can you clarify.

Comment: Yes i want to know how to get oobcode that is send in verify email.but through REST API because Firebase.Auth doesn't work on my editor @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: Ok, so you want to get the oobCode in order to call the REST API. How do you send the "email verification" email? Do you also use the REST API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-send-email-verification)?

Comment: Yes i want oobcode to confirm my email.all of my code is in REST API format. Can you plz tell me how to get this oobcode that is send in email

Answer (score 2):

The link in the "email verification" email contains the `oobCode` as a query string parameter. There is actually no way to generate this code via the Firebase Authentication API or via the Admin SDKs.

So, you need to extract the code from the query string and call the [REST API endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-confirm-email-verification) with this code.

---

Note that you can customize the "action URL" included in the email (i.e. the link in the "email verification" email) through the Firebase console (click on the "Authentication" vertical menu item, then on the "Templates" tab). For example you can point to a web page that you host, which calls the REST API after having parsed the `oobCode` value from the URL.

Comment: how can i extract the Oobcode from the query string

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @SuhaimKhalid Hello, you may accept the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Thanks!